# Error: unexpected end of file at Zlib._handle.onerror (zlib.js:355:17)

Tags: node.js

I am new in Node.js. 
when I decompressed input.txt.gz got an error. 
this is the error
Error: unexpected end of file at Zlib._handle.onerror (zlib.js:355:17).

I am using this code

```
var zlib = require('zlib');

//Decompress the file input.txt.gz to input.txt
var gunzip = zlib.createGunzip();

fs.createReadStream('input.txt.gz')
   .pipe(gunzip).pipe(fs.createWriteStream('input.txt'));

gunzip.on('error', function(error){
    console.log('Error occurs: '+error.stack);
});

console.log('File decompreessed.');
```

Comment: Try running `gunzip -vt input.txt.gz` on the file to see if it's not actually broken.

Comment: how to run this I only have a file and run a command "node filename.js" to show the output on the console.

Comment: It depends on the operating system that you use, but for Linux and macOS you can run that command from the terminal. For Windows, you can probably use a decompression application that may be able to check the validity of the file.